# middleware performing on all functions instead of ones just specified

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this middleware function:

```
 function authCheck (req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.loggedin) {

        next();

    } else {

        req.session.destroy();
        res.redirect('/login')

   }

}

module.exports = { authCheck }
```

I then retrieve it on my `index.js` page, in my root dir

```
const { authCheck } = require('./middleware/auth')
app.use(authCheck)
```

it works a little to good to say the least. Basically, I have a `routes` folder, and in there I have a file called `payments.js`. Inside that file, I have this:

```
 const {
    response
} = require("express");
var express = require("express");
const session = require('express-session');
var ibmdb = require("ibm_db");
var alert = require("alert");
const {
    render
} = require("ejs");
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const http = require('http').Server(express);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const saltRounds = 10;
var crypto = require("crypto");
    
const app = express();

//initialize session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret-key',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    maxage: 10
}))

app.get('/payment', (req, res) => {
    res.render('paymentCode.ejs')
})

app.post('/paymentsPage', (req, res) => {
    var userCode = req.body.code;

    var code = "select * from testclients"
        ibmdb.open(ibmdbconnMaster, function(err, conn) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            conn.query(code, function(err, rows) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }

                for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    if (rows[i]["CODE"] != userCode) {
                        console.log("unsuccessful")
                    } else {
                        res.render("makePayment", {
                            page_title: "makePayment",
                            data: rows,
                        })
                    }
                }

                conn.close(function() {
                    // console.log("closed the function /index");
                });
            });
        });
})
module.exports = app
```

standard stuff. by no means do I have `authCheck` anywhere to be found there, but for some strange reason, it is performing the `authCheck` functionality on this function, although I don't need it to. is this normal, or am I missing something? I can share `index.js` page if needed

Comment: additionally, you should directly select the code in the query with a WHERE clause, vs looping through every row in the table

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks for bringing that up. I am actually trying that right now, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67892601/how-to-log-something-if-query-returned-empty . my problem there is if the query returns nothing, then nothing happens!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are using the same `app` instance you exported from `payments.js`. So when you do a `app.use(authCheck)` in your `index.js` it is applying that middleware to entire application not to specific routes.

In order to achieve what you want you can use `express.Router`.
See this link https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Here is some example code from the link above.
This is your `payments.js` (Ignore the routes)

```js
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

// middleware that is specific to this router
router.use(function timeLog (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time: ', Date.now())
  next()
})
// define the home page route
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Birds home page')
})
// define the about route
router.get('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.send('About birds')
})

module.exports = router
```

And in your `index.js` use it like this:

```js
var payments = require('./payments.js')

// ...

app.use('/payments', payments)
```

Edit: I have just pasted this sample code from documentation just to demonstrate how you can use `express.Router` to apply middlewares for specific routes. Please refer to documentation for clearer understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added middleware as

```
app.use(authCheck)
```

of course, it should be called for all endpoints in your service.
If you need to specify a middleware for specific routes, you can do it by

```
router.get('/user', authCheck, function (req, res) {
  res.send('Profile')
})
```

Or, you can specify the logic in you're middleware, to ignore the routes, which don't need authentication, You can do it by regex, or by checking specific routes and use `app.use(authCheck)` in the root.
For instance

```
 function authCheck(req, res, next) {
    const nonSecurePaths = ['/user', '/example'];
    if (req.session.loggedin || nonSecurePaths.includes(req.path)) {
        next();
    } else {
        req.session.destroy();
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
}
```